# Extract value from combobox in gwidgets2

Tags: r, function, gwidgets

```
w <- gwindow(title="Example",visible=TRUE)
g = ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, cont=w)
values=c(1,2,3,4,5)
temp <- gcombobox(values,cont=g)
gbutton("Add the value to the list", cont=g,handler = function(...){
  ###### Store in a vector e.g. stored <- c(stored,svalue(temp))   #######
})

print(stored)
```

I let user select value from a combo-box and when the user wants to add that value in to a vector , I provide a **button** to add the value, but how can I store the **svalue(combobox)** as it will be null inside the **handler** of the button. Also if I pass it I wouldn't be able to store it in a **global vector**.

Comment: The usual R convention of using a `<-` function to modify a value is not available with a callback. You need to use other tricks to modify a value outside the scope of the function call. I'd suggest defining an environment as part of your application (`e <- new.env()`, say) and then within the handler, assigning to that: `e$stored <- svalue(temp)`. This change will be visible outside the callback.

Comment: @jverzani Hi John, Thank you for your reply. I wasn't aware we can do something like this. Is using Global variables another option?

Comment: Yes. You can use the `<<-` assignment operator to assign in a parent environment, typically this being the global environment. The only drawback here is namespace pollution and possible name collision, but for simple scripts this is generally useful.